# Perform sidekiq worker manually

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, sidekiq, worker

I have a Sidekiq worker called `class Consolidation::AnalyticsWorker < BaseWorker`

I want to perform it manually for testing
How can I achieve this?

Tried in rails console:

```
test = Consolidation::AnalyticsWorker
perform(test)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to do something like `Consolidation::AnalyticsWorker.new.perform(args)` where args are arguments which method `Consolidation::AnalyticsWorker#perform` takes.